# VB6 Getting Error when inputting apostrophe on Filter, using ADODB

Tags: vb6, ado

I'm trying to filter datagrid from a textbox it works but not if apostrophe or ' was typed on the textbox, I'm using ADODB and VB6

```
Public Sub pGetCustomer(Optional vSearch As String)

  If vSearch = "'" Then
  xRSTree.Filter = adFilterNone
  xRSTree.Requery
Else
    xRSTree.Filter = "description like '%" & vSearch & "%' or customercode like '%" & vSearch & "%'"
End If

Private Sub txtSearch_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
KeyAscii = Asc(UCase(Chr(KeyAscii)))

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to "escape" your qoutes or single qoutes. Simple way would be to replace in vSearch all ' with '' and all " with "".

Answer (score 3):

As it says in the ADO documentation (when did people fall into this weird habit of calling ADO "ADODB" anyway???):

> **Note**   To include single quotation marks (') in the filter Value, use two single quotation marks to represent one. For example, to filter on `O'Malley`, the criteria string should be `"col1 = 'O''Malley'"`. To include single quotation marks at both the beginning and the end of the filter value, enclose the string with pound signs (#). For example, to filter on `'1'`, the criteria string should be `"col1 = #'1'#"`.

You must also consider wildcard rules here:

> If Operator is **LIKE**, Value can use wildcards. Only the asterisk (`*`) and percent sign (`%`) wild cards are allowed, and they must be the last character in the string. Value cannot be `null`.

But a little confusingly:

> In a **LIKE** clause, you can use a wildcard at the beginning and end of the pattern (for example, `LastName Like '*mit*'`), or only at the end of the pattern (for example, `LastName Like 'Smit*'`).